# Java DAO pattern multiple table atomic transaction

Tags: java, database, jdbc, dao

I'm trying to use the DAO pattern to insert into two tables that has one-to-one relationship. I have `customer` and `address` tables. Every `customer` has an `address_id` field which references the id of the `address` table.

What I want to do is insert the customer address into the `address` table and get the generated `address_id` and use that to insert the customer into the `customer` table. If any of those tasks failed, the database left unchanged.

I'm not using any framework like spring or hibernate, just plain JDBC with DAO pattern.

Here is the code. In `Application.java`, first I insert the address and then insert the customer. if the customer insertion fails the address remains in database.

I can turn off the auto commit of database connection and merge the address and customer insertion in one database connection, but does that correspond with the DAO pattern?

Customer.java:

```
package com.example.model;

public class Customer {

   private long id;
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   private String email;
   private byte[] salt;
   private byte[] digest;
   private Address address;

   // getters and setters
}
```

Address.java:

```
package com.example.model;

public class Address {

    private long id;
    private String address;
    private String postalCode;
    private String phone;

    // getters and setters
}
```

AddressDAO.java:

```
package com.example.dao;

import com.example.model.Address;

public interface AddressDAO {

    void create(Address address);
}
```

AddressDAOImpl.java:

```
package com.example.dao;

import com.example.model.Address;
import com.example.util.DatabaseUtil;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class AddressDAOImpl implements AddressDAO {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AddressDAOImpl.class);

    @Override
    public void create(Address address) {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO address (address, postal_code, phone) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
        try (PreparedStatement ps = DatabaseUtil.getConnection()
                .prepareStatement(sql, PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) {
            ps.setString(1, address.getAddress());
            ps.setString(2, address.getPostalCode());
            ps.setString(3, address.getPhone());
            ps.executeUpdate();
            try (ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys()) {
                if (rs.next()) {
                    address.setId(rs.getShort(1));
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

CustomerDAO.java:

```
package com.example.dao;

import com.example.model.Customer;

public interface CustomerDAO {

    void create(Customer customer);
}
```

CustomerDOAImpl.java:

```
package com.example.dao;

import com.example.model.Customer;
import com.example.util.DatabaseUtil;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class CustomerDAOImpl implements CustomerDAO {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomerDAOImpl.class);

    @Override
    public void create(Customer customer) {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO customer (first_name, last_name, email, address_id, salt, digest) " +
            "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        try (PreparedStatement ps = DatabaseUtil.getConnection()
                .prepareStatement(sql, PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)){
            ps.setString(1, customer.getFirstName());
            ps.setString(2, customer.getLastName());
            ps.setString(3, customer.getEmail());
            ps.setLong(4, customer.getAddress().getId());
            ps.setBytes(5, customer.getSalt());
            ps.setBytes(6, customer.getDigest());
            ps.executeUpdate();
            try (ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys()) {
                if (rs.next()) {
                    customer.setId(rs.getLong(1));
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Application.java:

```
package com.example;

import com.example.dao.AddressDAO;
import com.example.dao.AddressDAOImpl;
import com.example.dao.CustomerDAO;
import com.example.dao.CustomerDAOImpl;
import com.example.model.Address;
import com.example.model.Customer;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        Address address = new Address();
        CustomerDAO customerDAO = new CustomerDAOImpl();
        AddressDAO addressDAO = new AddressDAOImpl();

        address.setAddress("Address");
        address.setPostalCode("123456789");
        address.setPhone("987654321");

        customer.setFirstName("John");
        customer.setLastName("Doe");
        customer.setEmail("john.doe@mail.com");
        customer.setAddress(address);

        addressDAO.create(customer.getAddress());
        customerDAO.create(customer);

        System.out.println(customer.getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want things to execute atomically, then you need to use transactions, if that _"that corresponds with the DAO pattern"_ is a matter of opinion. Patterns are guidance, not law.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a one-to-one relationship and assuming you wouldn't create an Address by itself, I would just put the creation of Address within the CustomerDAOImpl. Later, you could expose retrieval of Address objects in a AddressDAO later if ever necessary. Updates to the Address could also be handled via the same CustomerDAOImpl class.

This approach would work better in the long term if you were to transition to JPA/Hibernate in the future where the same behavior would be exhibited by the framework. Plus, this prevents you from having to make your own transaction/connection management between DAO classes.